# ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value em SELECT

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, oracle11g

Estou enfrentando um problema com duas consultas distintas no `oracle`. Ambas possuem o trecho de sql `REPLACE(dbms_lob.substr(wm_concat(disctinct <COLUNA>)), ',', ', ')`

O erro que retorna é o `ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value`.

Procurei pelo erro no `SOPT` e no `SOEN` mas nenhuma das respostas, ou perguntas, me deu alguma luz sobre o assunto. A maioria das questões trata sobre erros no `INSERT`, mas o meu problema é no `SELECT`.

Ambas as consultas possuem pelo menos um `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

A versão utilizada do `oracle` é `11g`.

Quando executo o SQL no `PL/SQL` nenhum erro resulta, mas ao utilizar a biblioteca de acesso ao banco de dados oracle para o C# ocorre o erro.

O SQL abaixo é o utilizado por uma das consultas:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT ROWNUM NUM_REG, queryResult.*
          FROM (

                SELECT anp.id_klient "C",
                        anp.bruecke_1 "L",
                        anp.cod_conhec "Conhec",
                        anp.charge_ref "Ref. L",
                        anp.valor_cif "Valor CIF",
                        w.nr_doc "Documento",
                        w.datum_we "Dt. E",
                        SUM(q.mng_frei) "Qtd. D",
                        TRUNC(anp.datum_gera) "Dt. PC",
                        REPLACE(dbms_lob.substr(NVL(wm_concat(DISTINCT a8.nr_di),
                                                    empty_clob())),
                                ',',
                                ', ') "DI",
                        REPLACE(dbms_lob.substr(wm_concat(DISTINCT
                                                          TO_CHAR(a8.time_neu,
                                                                  'dd/mm/yyyy'))),
                                ',',
                                ', ') "Dt. C DI",
                        REPLACE(dbms_lob.substr(NVL(wm_concat(DISTINCT a8.nr_da),
                                                    empty_clob())),
                                ',',
                                ', ') "DA",
                        REPLACE(dbms_lob.substr(NVL(wm_concat(DISTINCT ak.bez_1),
                                                    empty_clob())),
                                ',',
                                ', ') "Mercadoria",
                        REPLACE(dbms_lob.substr(NVL(wm_concat(DISTINCT
                                                              w.nr_zoll),
                                                    empty_clob())),
                                ',',
                                ', ') "CP",
                        REPLACE(dbms_lob.substr(NVL(wm_concat(DISTINCT w.laenge),
                                                    empty_clob())),
                                ',',
                                ', ') "T C",
                        REPLACE(dbms_lob.substr(NVL(wm_concat(DISTINCT
                                                              TO_CHAR(a4.time_out,
                                                                      'dd/mm/yyyy')),
                                                    empty_clob())),
                                ',',
                                ', ') "Dt. S",
                        REPLACE(dbms_lob.substr(NVL(wm_concat(distinct
                                                              TO_CHAR(a4.time_end_unload,
                                                                      'dd/mm/yyyy')),
                                                    empty_clob())),
                                ',',
                                ', ') "Dt. D"
                  FROM wms.quanten q
                 INNER JOIN wms.we w
                    ON (w.lager = q.lager AND
                       w.nr_lieferschein = REPLACE(q.charge, 'AG', 'AD') AND
                       w.nr_zoll = TRIM(q.trenn_3))
                 INNER JOIN wms.anliefpos anp
                    ON (anp.lager = q.lager AND anp.id_klient = q.id_klient AND
                       anp.bruecke_1 = REPLACE(q.charge, 'AG', 'AD'))
                 INNER JOIN wms.artikel ak
                    ON (ak.id_artikel = q.id_artikel)
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN wms.desmembr a8
                    ON (a8.lager = anp.lager AND a8.id_klient = anp.id_klient AND
                       a8.lote_ad = anp.bruecke_1 AND
                       a8.typ_process = 'DINACI')
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN wms.contcontrol a4
                    ON (a4.nr_container = w.nr_zoll AND a4.document = w.nr_doc AND
                       a4.lager = w.lager AND a4.stat = 90 AND
                       a4.stat_oc = 00)
                 WHERE q.lager = :estabelecimento
                   AND q.id_klient = :cliente HAVING SUM(q.mng_frei) > 0
                 GROUP BY anp.bruecke_1,
                           anp.cod_conhec,
                           anp.charge_ref,
                           anp.valor_cif,
                           w.nr_doc,
                           w.datum_we,
                           anp.id_klient,
                           anp.lager,
                           anp.datum_gera
                 ORDER BY anp.bruecke_1

                ) queryResult)
 WHERE NUM_REG > :limiteInferior
   AND NUM_REG <= :limiteSuperior
```

Gostaria de saber o motivo pelo qual é gerada exceção e como poderia tratá-la.

**Edição**

Consegui descobrir que se remover o `SQL` responsável pela paginação da query o resultado vem como esperado. Porém, preciso da paginação para uma eventual consulta que retorna muitos registros.

Inicialmente meus limites são, respectivamente inferior e superior, 0 e 35.

A query resulta em um total de 72 resultados, gerando 3 páginas.

**Edição 2**

Imagem do erro que ocorre:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quantas linhas sua consulta retornar? já fez um count?

Comment: Retorna aproximada mente 30 linhas. Nenhuma algumas delas possui mais de um resultado, porém algumas delas retornam vazias no PL/SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não consegui descobrir o motivo pelo qual o erro ocorria, mas após dois dias tentando, consegui solucionar o meu problema.

Caso alguém saiba o motivo do erro e tenha resultados mais detalhados serão muito bem vindos.

Eu tenho um método que realiza a paginação de um `SQL` qualquer, conforme código abaixo:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
       SELECT queryResult.*, ROWNUM numero
         FROM (
              {0}
         ) queryResult
  )
 WHERE numero > {1}
   AND numero <= {2}
```

Utilizando esse código com o `SQL` "CORE" ocorria o erro. Um colega (Hendrig) me falou sobre umas funções analíticas do `Oracle` e me ajudou, até que conseguimos chegar a um resultado satisfatório. Parece um pouco de Gambiarra, mas funcionou.

Modificamos o `SQL` da paginação para o comando abaixo e o resultado foi o esperado:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
     SELECT queryResult.*, DENSE_RANK() over (order by rownum desc) numero
       FROM (
            {0}
       ) queryResult
)
 WHERE numero BETWEEN {1} AND {2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alguns dos valores como nr_di, nr_da, bez_1, laenge, nr_zoll, time_out, time_end_unload podem estar retornando nulo e a função NVL esta substituindo esse valor nulo por empty_clob()

Como o empty_clob esta vazio você não pode usa-lo como um parâmetro para a DBMS_LOB package conforme explicitado na documentação em

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions047.htm

Comment: Mas mesmo antes de adicionar o `empty_lob()` dava erro.

Comment: dbms_lob não esta recebendo parâmetro adequado.

Comment: QUando executo o SQL "CORE", removendo os `SELECTS` para paginação funciona. Então não consegui entender a lógica do erro.